# F3 Cortex and Many to Many relation

Tags: orm, many-to-many, fat-free-framework

I'm building a simple app using F3 and Cortex but I'm running in some problems trying to create a simple Many to Many relation. Its just two tables (and a third, from the relation), the tables already exist and have some data:

```
class User extends \DB\Cortex {

protected
        $fieldConf = array(
            'name' => array (
                'type' => 'VARCHAR128',
                'nullable' => false,
                'required' => true,
                ),
            'email' => array (
                'type' => 'VARCHAR256',
                'nullable' => false,
                'required' => true,
                ),
            'password' => array (
                'type' => 'VARCHAR128',
                'nullable' => false,
                'required' => true,
                ),
//                'groups' => array(
//                    'has-many' => array('Group', 'group_id', 'user_has_group')
//                )
                ),
        $db = 'db',
        $table = 'user';
}
```

and

```
class Group extends \DB\Cortex {

protected
        $fieldConf = array(
            'name' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR128',
                'nullable' => false,
                'required' => true,
            ),
            'description' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR128',
                'nullable' => false,
                'required' => true,
            ),
//                'users' => array(
//                    'has-many' => array('User', 'user_id', 'user_has_group')
//                )
                ),
        $db = 'db',
        $table = 'group';
}
```

accourind with this [model of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ivcc.png)

But if I remove those comment marks, I get a strange error while acessing anything:

**Internal Server Error
No valid DB Connection given.**

And on refresh:

**Internal Server Error
Fatal error: Leaked 1 hashtable iterators**

It looks silly, but I searched all over and spent the better part of a whole day, and still can't seem to make it work.

Comment: regarding the 2nd issue, it's maybe just a php 7 bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71470 and regarding issue #1 I'm not sure. At least it's currently not possible to define custom fields for the pivot table. the 2nd array parameter was meant be equal the has-many field in the foreign model...that feature request was already made though.

Comment: Since I asked, I changed the model, even build it with ekhaled/f3-cortex-model-generator, its syntax should be ok now, and yet no dice. Every time I call the model, the DB stops responding, same error as before. The error originates from:cortex.php:263] DB\Cortex->__construct()
cortex.php:545] DB\Cortex::resolveConfiguration()
cortex.php:160] DB\Cortex::resolveRelationConf()
cortex.php:127] DB\Cortex->initMapper()